# Learning noncommutative algebraic geometry

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, noncommutative-geometry

What are the prerequisites (I.e. Which textbooks/reference) and what's the recommended route at learning noncommutative algebraic geometry?

Comment: What noncommutative algebraic geometry? There're several models.